# Running simple example using Spark and Hive throws exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

Following [these](https://kontext.tech/column/spark/560/apache-spark-301-installation-on-linux-guide) instructions, I am attempting to run a simple program that uses `Spark` and `Hive` together:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
appName = "PySpark Hive Example"
master = "local[*]"
spark = SparkSession.builder \
             .appName(appName) \
             .master(master) \
             .enableHiveSupport() \
             .getOrCreate()
# Read data using Spark
df = spark.sql("show databases")
df.show()
```

I get this exception:

```
2021-07-25 20:46:21,477 WARN DataNucleus.Query: Query for candidates of org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MConstraint and subclasses resulted in no possible candidates
Class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase" field "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase.catalogName" : declared in MetaData, but this field doesnt exist in the class!
org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidClassMetaDataException: Class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase" field "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase.catalogName" : declared in MetaData, but this field doesnt exist in the class!
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populateMemberMetaData(ClassMetaData.java:846)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:219)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl$1.run(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2896)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.populateAbstractClassMetaData(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2890)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.populateFileMetaData(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:2689)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.loadXMLMetaDataForClass(JDOMetaDataManager.java:806)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.getMetaDataForClassInternal(JDOMetaDataManager.java:406)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1660)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:1607)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData.getReferencedClassMetaData(AbstractClassMetaData.java:1634)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractClassMetaData.getReferencedClassMetaData(AbstractClassMetaData.java:1592)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.getReferencedClassMetaData(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:3108)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.getReferencedClasses(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:3078)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTables(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2998)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2886)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:119)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.manageClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1627)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:672)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.RDBMSQueryUtils.getStatementForCandidates(RDBMSQueryUtils.java:425)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JDOQLQuery.java:865)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.compileInternal(JDOQLQuery.java:347)
        at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1816)
        at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1744)
        at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.execute(Query.java:1726)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:374)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.ensureDbInit(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:588)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:431)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6902)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1707)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:83)
        ...

NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
Identifier principalName is unresolved (not a static field)
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Identifier principalName is unresolved (not a static field)
```

Not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue while setting up a new Hive/Hadoop cluster. I was using the Hive Metastore embedded within the Hive Server, and was able to get Spark to work by setting up a separate Hive Metastore as described in [The Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Metastore+Administration#AdminManualMetastoreAdministration-RemoteMetastoreServer), and then setting `hive.metastore.uris` in `$SPARK_CONF_DIR/hive-site.xml` to the thrift URL of that new external Metastore.

Comment: When sharing outside links, please be sure to quote the appropriate sections in your answers. Links may become dead or outdated in the future so it always best practice to have a "snapshot" of the relevant information in your answer.